# Using two identical POS printers via JavaPOS

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, javapos

We are writing one app using JavaPOS that requires printing to two identical POS printers (Bixolon SRP-330) via JavaPOS (one using regular paper, other for stickers)

What would be the best approach to handle such use case? 
We tried creating double entry in jpos.xml, directly specifying portname in jpos properties but still no luck, we are only able to use one of those printers at the same time using JavaPOS and logical device name.

(At lower  level echo "test > /dev/usb/lp0 and echo "test > /dev/usb/lp1 print to both printers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is the problem with Bixolon JavaPOS drivers. We contacted their support and they said that they understand the problem and they will address this issue in future driver release.
Meanwhile we managed to circumvent JavaPOS and are communicating with printers on lower level.

Comment: Dear friend, I have a Vega7000 Series  EFT-POS terminal. Do you have any idea how can I develop program for it? What kind of tools and IDEs and Documents am I need? Where can I find this requirements? And does it have JVM? i.e. does it support Java applications or I must use another programming language? Any light on this issue highly appreciated.

Comment: We managed to get help by contacting manufacturer customer support. So I advise you to try the same.

Comment: As my country is boycotted according to American law, I can't contact them. (I sent emails but I don't receive any response.). May I ask you to give some elementary information about Vega 7000, if you have.  (SDK/IDE Plugin/Documents and so on)