# Connect and Print with 2 or multiple identical thermal printers using the identical JavaPOS/OPOS driver?

Tags: opos, javapos

### REQUEST

I created a POS app (based on Java) that needs to be connected to at least 2 **identical** thermal printers using the **same driver** and the printers should do:

- at application **start** >> each printer is to be `open(),claim(),setDeviceEnable(true)` **once**
- at application **stop** >> each printer is to be    `setDeviceEnable(false),release(),close()`
- food items to be printed on POSPrinter1
- drink items to be printed on POSPrinter2

### WHAT I TRIED SO FAR

I created two POSPrinter objects

```
private POSPrinter posprinter = initUSBPrinter("POSPrinter1");
private POSPrinter posprinter2 = initUSBPrinter("POSPrinter2");

private static POSPrinter initUSBPrinter(String printerName) {
    POSPrinter ptr = new POSPrinter();
    try {
        ptr.open(printerName);
        ptr.claim(1000);
        ptr.setDeviceEnabled(true);
    } catch (JposException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ptr ;
}
```

- NO ERROR during application start when both printers were initiated/claimed
- WORKS FINE while printing food items with POSPrinter1
- ERROR OCCURRED shown below while trying to print drink items with POSPrinter2:

  jpos.JposException: 103
  at com.sewoo.jpos.POSPrinterService.printNormal(POSPrinterService.java:4130)
  at jpos.POSPrinter.printNormal(Unknown Source)
  at util.PrintManager.printOrderingHeaderByPrinter(PrintManager.java:628)
  at util.PrintManager.printDrinkByPrinter(PrintManager.java:1359)
  at util.PrintManager.printOrdering(PrintManager.java:1931)
  at util.PrintManager.lambda$print$17(PrintManager.java:1668)
  at ...

### ISSUE

So while both printers were found during init/claim, somehow POSPrinter1 could print perfectly fine while POSPrinter2 throws `jpos.POSPrinter.printNormal(Unknown Source)`. I suspect that since POSPrinter1 was claimed before POSPrinter2, the JavaPOS driver is only connected to POSPrinter1. So is it possible that a single JavaPOS driver can only talk to a single device?

> To be able to talk to 2 printing devices simultaneously do I need to
>   have 2 JavaPOS drivers installed? If so, how can I configure my app to
>   do so?

### THIS WORKS BUT SLOWS PRINTING PROCESS

- connect to a either printer via `open(),claim(),setDeviceEnable(true)`
  before the printjob
- and disconnect the printer via `setDeviceEnable(false),release(),close()` after the successful run of the printjob

BUT connect/disconnect after each print job slows down the printing process considerably. I usually need to wait 3-5 secs after the printjob was sent to see the printer finally printing the slip.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with that printer manufacturer's JavaPOS. 
Please try another manufacturer's printer.

Comment: @kunif thanks for your reply. What do you suggest could be wrong? Do you think that my approach to create 2 instances of POSPrinter is actually the right way to do it?

Comment: Under the JavaPOS specification, your way of doing it will be correct. 
In my experience, OPOS/POS for. NET can independently control two devices in the same way.

Comment: Just like StackOverfow's Related Q&A [Using two identical POS printers via JavaPOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930527/using-two-identical-pos-printers-via-javapos?rq=1) was listed.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your input. I contacted my hardware manufacturer.

Comment: I´m in the same situation. do you find any workaround?. It seems like JavaPOs can´t print in 2 pos-printers at the same time. It only works with sequential printing.

Comment: @Andres unfortunately this is caused by JavaPOS. We abandoned it and now we are using ESCPOS only.

Comment: you may try it from two different class loaders. Maybe they have just state problems with the driver. Just start the application twice and print simultanusly